# How to configure Client VPN network interfaces in Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/what-is.html Network Interfaces will be created for the Client VPN, and I can see that in AWS Console there are two network interfaces which have been allocated IPs in my Subnet, their descriptions are like `ClientVPN Endpoint resource. EndpointId: cvpn-endpoint-0ee35c5e95a01400c`.

How can I define the IP addresses for these interfaces?
I can't seem to find the relevant options on the resource `aws_ec2_client_vpn_endpoint` to control this.

Comment: I think you're looking for `aws_ec2_client_vpn_network_association` which associates the Client VPN with a specific subnet. It doesn't look like you are able to specify exact IP addresses though. Why do you need to control those IPs? You are able to assign security groups, which can then be used in other security group rules.

Comment: @MarkB Sorry for the delay. My reasoning was that I would like to know in advance what the IPs of my VPN Network Interfaces will be. Also if I can keep control over those IP addresses, then I can ensure that I don't issue any IPs that inadvertently clash with them. I can't see any documentation on how they are chosen, it seems they are allocated randomly? Any thoughts?

Comment: It does look like they are allocated randomly. Do you need to know the IP from within other Terraform code?

Comment: @MarkB I have the scenario whereby I allocate a bunch of network interfaces for EC2 instances with static IPs. I am not clear how I can be certain that I don't allocate an IP for such an EC2 instance, which doesn't conflict with the VPN interface IPs?